# close bootstrap modal in react-redux programmatically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, redux

trust we all doing great...I am currently building a react application also making use of redux, I am having an issue trying to close modal in bootstarp programmatically, I am using **bootstrap 4**, and **jquery 3.3.1**... I have tried this:

```
 onSubmit(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
    this.props.editBusinessAction(this.props.id, this.state)
      .then((message) => {
        $('#modal').modal(hide)
      toastrOption();
      toastr.success(message);
   })
  .catch((message) => {
    toastrOption();
    toastr.error(message);
    console.log(message);
  });
```

}

Comment: you need to add '' in `hide`, like this `$('#modal').modal('hide')`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `hide` in quotes like this:

```
 onSubmit(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
    this.props.editBusinessAction(this.props.id, this.state)
      .then((message) => {
        $('#modal').modal('hide')
      toastrOption();
      toastr.success(message);
   })
  .catch((message) => {
    toastrOption();
    toastr.error(message);
    console.log(message);
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> $('#modal').modal('hide') this works only when you import jquery and bootstrap in your entry component.

install jquery and bootstrap and import jquery in your starting component eg: App.js like below

> npm install -s jquery@2.2.3 bootstrap@3.3.6

**App.js**

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
export default class extends Component {
    render(){
      return (
         <div>App component</App>
      )
    }
}
```